# Not displaying in UI after code refactoring

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, refactoring

I am trying to refactor my Android Firebase project, to move code for inserting data into database and for displaying UI from MainActivity to MessageDao class.

This is my MessageDao class:

```
public class MessageDao {
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");;

    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messages);

    public void write(Message message){
        mMessagesDatabaseRef.push().setValue(message);

    }

    public void updateList(){
        mMessagesDatabaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                messages.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class));

                mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Message msg = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

And MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


     .....


    private MessageDao mesageDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);


        mesageDao = new MessageDao();

        .....



        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Message message = new Message(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                mesageDao.write(message);

                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        mesageDao.updateList();

    }


}
```

When I click `mSendButton` button, it writes into database, but it's not displaying in my UI. When `childEventListener` is in `MainActivity` it all works fine, but when I move it to `MessageDao` and call it in MainActivity `onCreate` method with `mesageDao.updateList()` it's not working. So, what am I missing here ?

Comment: How are you getting mMessageAdapter in activity?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, your MessageDao class in which you have moved the code, needs to extends Application like this:

```
public class MessageDao extends Application {...}
```

Hope it helps.